# Python - Search list for value in dataframe column, append result of operation involving other column to list

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a list of strings, like so:

```
m = ['First Officer', 'Executive Officer']
```

As well as a Pandas dataframe like so:

```
d = {'match': ['and', 'first'], 'use': ['&', '1st']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I'd like to `re.search` every string in the `m` for every substring in `df.match`, and when there is a match, to append the `re.sub` of `m[i]` and `df.match[i]` for the respective `df.use[i]` to `m`.

Expected output is:

```
>> ['First Officer', 'Executive Officer', '1st Officer']
```

What would the fastest implementation of this be?

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Comment: Sure thing. @Rakesh

Comment: what pandas functions have you tried so far to solve this?

Comment: What have you tried? What is not working?

Comment: @harvpan Nested for loops and pandas apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a helper function to handle replacements:

```
def helper(mtch):
     return df.loc[df.match.eq(mtch.group().lower()), 'use'].values[0]
```

Then use a list comprehension with **`re.sub`**:

```
[
    re.sub(r'|'.join(df.match.values), lambda x: helper(x), i, flags=re.I)
    for i in m
]
# ['1st Officer', 'Executive Officer']
```

If you really want the originals too:

```
set(m + [re.sub(r'|'.join(df.match.values), lambda x: helper(x), i, flags=re.I) for i in m])
# {'1st Officer', 'Executive Officer', 'First Officer'}
```

Personally, I think it would be easier to accomplish this by using a dictionary instead of a dataframe, which allows for much easier lookup:

```
dct = dict(df.values)
# {'and': '&', 'first': '1st'}

[
    re.sub(r'|'.join(dct.keys()),
    lambda x: dct[x.group().lower()], i, flags=re.I)
    for i in m
]
# ['1st Officer', 'Executive Officer']
```